# Show Number Only Value For [num]E+N

Tags: javascript, excel

### What I'm Trying To Achieve:

To show a number only value for `[num]E+N`

**Number Input:** 1.04802E+14

- **.toFixed(0) Output:** 104802000000000
- **Manual Output (see fun below):** 104802000000000
- **Microsoft Excel Output:** 104802495605190

**My Function Attempt:**

```js
exponent("1.04802E+14");

function exponent(n) {
  n = n.replace('E', '').split('+');
  var num = n[0];
  var x = n[1];
  var i = 0;
  while (i < x) {
    num = num * 10;
    i++;
  }
  console.log(num);
}
```

### Questions:

1. Is Excel Wrong?

   - If not, how can I find the number only value?

Comment: Try putting both values in excel in different cells and see output.

Comment: Do you mean `E` used by `javascript` programming language, and not the mathematical irrational constant _`e`_?

Comment: On a side note: `n[0] * (10 ** n[1])` is shorter than doing the while loop.

Comment: With the Excel method, I refer to placing `1.04802E+14` in a cell and changing the call value to `number`.

Comment: Or `n[0] * Math.pow(10, n[1])` in ES5.